# Manually add NSRange to NSMutableIndexSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsindexpath, nsrange

I have been trying to add NSRanges to an NSMutableIndexSet (for later enumeration) however I think I am misunderstanding what `addIndexesinRange` does. At an early point I `NSMakeRange` "x" number of ranges that I create from a previous `NSIndexSet`.

Such as:

```
    "NSRange: {0, 29}",
    "NSRange: {63, 96}",
    "NSRange: {132, 177}",
    "NSRange: {222, 269}",
    "NSRange: {284, 306}",
    "NSRange: {321, 330}"
```

And trying to add them to the new set:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    for (int s=0; s < array; s++) {
        NSRange ran = [[array objectAtIndex:s]rangeValue];
        [indexSet addIndexesInRange:ran];
}
```

Returns

> [number of indexes: 617 (in 2 ranges),
>   indexes: (0-28 63-650)]

When I want it to return the same ranges as before just inside the set, any tips?

Comment: `NSRange` is start and length, not start and end.

Comment: So if I got the start and end of each NSRange and used "addIndexesInRange" would that return a NSIndexSet as hoped for above is that its intended use

Comment: Probably. Try it and see if it is. Define your ranges properly and it should work.

Comment: To be clear: the output you showed matches the input you showed. If the output isn't what you wanted, it's not because of the code you showed here, it's because of the input and whatever code created that.

Comment: Ok, yes rmaddy that worked,  - "NSRange ran = [[otherSleepArray objectAtIndex:s]rangeValue];
        NSUInteger b = ran.length - ran.location;
        [indexSet addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(ran.location, b)];